# Toggleclass not working, altough should

Tags: javascript, toggleclass

This is pretty basic, still doesn't work... I'm trying to change the class of my button, which has the id "nav_list". I wrote the script:

```
    var specialSection = document.getElementById("nav_list");
    specialSection.onclick = function() {
    alert("what");
    $('#nav_list').toggleClass('active');
    };
```

I get the "what" alert, but the class isn't toggled. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It must work can you provide a demo on jsfiddle? Why are you mixing vanilla and jQuery objects? You can write $('#nav_list').click(function(){... and $(this).toggleClass('active');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) is a jQuery method, for use it you must include jQuery in your page.

Like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

At the moment if you check the console you must see an error like (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/GyaBY/):

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

Avoid mixing jQuery and javascript event binding so your code will look like:

```
$('#nav_list').click(function() {
    alert("what");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/GyaBY/2/

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a complete newb, I don't even know the difference between vanilla an jquery... Now it's working. I thought "$" was basic, meaning a variable.

Comment: You are welcome! Start from js and than learn jQuery; happy coding!